# How to draw x=y line in OriginPro

Tags: scatter-plot

Does anyone know how to draw an exact x=y line in OriginPro scatter plot? I already looked into the Internet and OriginPro forums with no exact solution. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Firstly make a column of numbers in Excel (...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...), copy that. Then create a new Book in Origin, paste it in 2 columns: (X) and (Y). After highlight theese 2 columns with your cursor and go to Plot -> Line. That's it.

Comment: This seems logical.